# Arduino Mega 2560 + HC-05 Bluetooth in Master mode, AT+INQ responds with ERROR(16)

Tags: hc-05

I need to connect this arduino mega to an external device (ANT BMS which has integrated Bluetooth), and I need to find out the address of the ANT BMS, in the provided iPhone app, there are no informations regarding the bluetooth address, so I wanted to use this arduino, which anyway in the end will stay connected permanently to ANT BMS

After I connected HC-05 module to arduino I issued the commands bellow :

I connected HC-05 to RX and TX pins of my mega and issued the commands in serial monitor (set to 38400 and Both NL & CR)

```
AT
// responded : OK
AT+ROLE=1
// responded : OK
AT+ROLE?
// responded : +ROLE:1
AT+INQ
// responded : ERROR:(16)
```

I also tried to send the AT+INIT but after that command the led starts flashing quickly and it does not accept any other commands :frowning:

```
AT+STATE?
// responded: +STATE:INQUIRING
// OK
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HC-05 Bluetooth AT+INQ command not working](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/180962/hc-05-bluetooth-atinq-command-not-working)

Comment: No, That is what I first tried, but everytime after issuing the command AT+INIT command, the led starts flashing quickly and it does not responde to any other commands.

I also tried AT+CLASS=0, no help.

Does anyone knows why after AT+INIT the led starts flashing quickly, it does the same on your modules too ?

Comment: Today I tried again:

`AT+ORGL .... OK
AT+RMAAD .... OK
AT+ROLE=1 .... OK
AT+CMODE=1 .... OK
AT+INQ .... ERROR:(16)`

Comment: The ERROR(16) means : SPP lib hasn’t been initialized. but if I tried AT+INIT, the led starts flashing fast and **no commands are accepted anymore**, for any command I write, I get no response from the module :(